# Find the number of linearly independent matrices in any set of $n$ $5\times3$ matrixes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

No matrices are provided. Find the number of linearly independent matrices for any set of matrices. No need to find an example of an actual linearly independent set. I have no idea how to approach this problem.

What I know so far:
For all $5\times3$ matrices, you can form a basis with 15 matrices (ie. 1 in each [row, column] and 0s everywhere else). So if $n > 15$, at most 15 of them are linearly independent. But there can be fewer.

Comment: Without knowing anything about a set $S$ of vectors in a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$, all you can say is that the number of linearly independent vectors in $S$ is a natural number $\leq n$.

Answer (score 0):

The homework question was not specific. It wanted an algorithm to find the number of linearly independent vectors.

The solution is to make each 5x3 matrix a column vector by placing columns on top of each other to get a 15x1 column vector. Then take n 15x1 column vectors in a 15xn matrix. Apply transformations to get to the Reduced Row Echelon Form. Count the number of pivots. You now have the number of linearly independent matrices.